# Can I hire several veteran soldiers to accompany me?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, followers-and-hirelings

Seeing as one can hire guards for PC bases as 'Skilled Hirelings', can I take several veterans with me if I pay them enough?

I am a wizard with low HP, so any guards would be great.

I am playing in an Adventurers League game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In Adventurers' League, Not Sure

There isn't anything official one way or another about whether hirelings are legal in AL. They are in the PHB so they are part of the rules.

On the other hand, the AL DMG says "Services provided by an NPC are limited to this list." This could mean just the spellcasting services, or it could mean all services.

### There is a money cost and you probably can't afford it

Hirelings cost gold.

In AL season 8, gold is in short supply due to the treasure points rules. There are reports on the forums that PCs don't actually get enough gold to do class stuff.

When you get 75gp max per level at tier 1 and *revivify* costs 300gp, your cleric is not going to be raising many party members. When a fighter needs to be level 12 before they have enough gold for non-magical plate armour, extra gold for hirelings is probably not going to happen.

### There is an experience cost, but this probably doesn't apply

In home games, hirelings reduce the amount of XP your characters get.

From the DMG, chapter 8:

> If the party received substantial assistance from one or more NPCs, count those NPCs as party members when dividing up the XP. (Because the NPCs made the fight easier, individual characters receive fewer XP.)

There is nothing in the AL DMG about how this ties in with the milestone xp system, where xp is earned solely by sitting at the table (a per-hour rate) and achieving story goals.

### The other PCs

In all seriousness, the other characters are supposed to be guards. A party should be working to keep foes away from the artillery (sorcerer, warlock, wizard, any archer).

Comment: OP has stated that they have access to 7.5k gold (don't ask me how, I'd assume that they aren't using S8 rules). Assuming they aren't using the S8 rules they are using XP instead of AP.

Comment: Generally, if it is a none optional rule and not explicitly illegal, it is legal.

Answer (score 23):

### Yes, if your DM permits it.

Skilled hirelings can be any skilled service providers.

> Skilled hirelings include anyone hired to perform a service that
>   involves a proficiency (including weapon, tool, or skill): a
>   mercenary, artisan, scribe, and so on.

For example Veteran (MM 350):

> Veterans are professional fighters that take up arms for pay or to
>   protect something they believe in or value. Their ranks include
>   soldiers retired from long service and warriors who never served anyone
>   but themselves.

But always consider that the Services-Table on page 159 of the PHB shows the **minimum** wage and that hiring Veterans may be considerably more expensive or otherwise challenging.

> The pay shown is a minimum; some expert hirelings require more pay.

Your DM will tell you who or what is available or unavailable in their world and whether hirelings are available to you (AL DM 5).

Remember that experience of combat encounters is split with all characters, including NPCs (DMG 260, also D&D Adventurers League Player's Guide Version 2.0 Elemental Evil, Elemental Evil Edition page 11, and other places).

Comment: so with 7.5k I could get at least a thousand soldiers for a day?  AWESOME!

Comment: @EvokerofMulmaster if there are a thousand soldiers for hire and their wage allows that. _At least_ is a stretch, because maybe there won't be as many people available or your DM won't let you do it for some reason.

Comment: @EvokerofMulmaster Also ignoring the fact that there may not be such a large number of soldiers available, hiring such a great number of them may arouse some suspicion. Furthermore as a employee I'd prefer employment that does not last just for a single day...

Comment: @fabian is right. To quit steady job as, say, castle guard for just a day of employment wouldn't usually be wise so DM might well say no one is willing to do so, unless you pay hundreds times more than their usual wage.

Comment: There's also another factor--as a DM I would reject this on practical grounds, it would make combat take so long.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Do you actually run mass combats as hundreds of individuals? This would just run however you handle mass combat.

Comment: @TheNate This isn't mass combat, this is too many hirelings.  Abstracting away a mass combat is fine, but the squishy wizard is in the middle of this.

Answer (score 8):

I have no experience in running AL games so I can't speak much to how hired NPCs would work there. I imagine it wouldn't be much different though.

The most significant effect would be the reduction in XP each party member would gain as hirelings take an equal share of XP.

DMG p. 92:

> Any NPC that accompanies the adventurers ... earns a full share of the experience points.

This is true for both AL and non-AL games but I imagine the loss would be more significant for AL players as they move from game to game.

**Original Answer:**

Short answer: yes, page 159 of the PHB details hirelings, examples of skilled vs untrained ones, and costs of employing them. In your case, that would be 2gp per day, at a minimum, if your DM just goes by the table.

> Adventurers can pay nonplayer characters to assist them
>   or act on their behalf in a variety of circumstances. Most
>   such hirelings have fairly ordinary skills, while others
>   are masters of a craft or art, and a few are experts with
>   specialized adventuring skills.
>   ...
>   Skilled hirelings include anyone hired to perform a
>   service that involves a proficiency (including weapon,
>   tool, or skill): a mercenary, artisan, scribe, and so on.
>   The pay shown is a minimum; some expert hirelings
>   require more pay.

Slightly longer answer: depends on the DM and your group's playstyle.

Here's how I would handle this as a DM (our group is heavy on role-play and world-building):

First I'd determine if the number and skill level of any likely candidates. Is your current location a quiet backwater? Bustling city? A waypoint on a busy trade route? That would determine the quality and quantity of the available help.

Next I'd look at any competing employers. Are there better paying, safer, or more prestigious jobs available? Different NPCs will have different motivations.

Then I'd take a look at your character's reputation. What sort of adventures have you had, are you surly or charming, what sort of people do you associate with.

There are other factors but you get the idea. All that will help determine who'd be willing to work for you, for how much, how long, and what sort of tasks they will and won't accept.

That may mean the cost may be significantly higher than 2gp/day, their skills may or may not be up to par, and their loyalty and enthusiasm might only go so far.

This way the world feels more 'alive' to the players and brings out the 'C' in 'NPC'.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95581/discussion-on-answer-by-jcm-can-i-hire-several-veteran-soldiers-to-accompany-me).